# Does Kubernetes support Docker CE on Linux?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, windows-ce

I read about things that there are some Kubernetes issues with Docker support. As far as I understood Kubernetes doesn't support Docker CE on Linux. 
Does Kubernetes support Docker CE on Linux?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing prevents you from building a kubernetes cluster on top of `Docker CE`. It just isn't built-in on the CE-version (like it is in the windows version).

You can simply install `kubectl`, `kubeadm` and `kubelet` and create a cluster. There are multiple ways to set up the cluster to suit your needs. For local, single-node testing you can use [`minikube`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/minikube/), which is incredibly user friendly to set up.

Answer (score -1):

Kubernetes suppors Docker CE on Centos or RHEL.

Would you elaborate on the reason for the question pls

Comment: Thinking about architect an on-prem container infrastructure. I would like to orchestrate the system by using Kubernetes but I've heard something like Kubernetes can be used only with Docker-ee or I am wrong. Just wanted to be sure. We''ll have purchasing related restrictions for a while. So I wanted to know that Docker-ce can be used with Kubernetes or not.

Comment: Docker-ce can be used with Kubernetes. Identify  two Linux RHEL or Centos Box with 2 CPU /4GB RAM(min) and install Kubernetes and Docker-ce its straight forward if you follow some installation docs. Docker must show some proxy issues if you are behind corporate firewall. NTLM proxy won't work and you need to install CNTLM.Create one node as Master and the other as Docker host.

Comment: What about Photon OS or CoreOS instead of RHEL or Centos Box? Do I have any disadvantages If I use Photon OS or CoreOS both on Esxi?

Comment: VMWare has its own container support via vSphere integrating Kub's and Docker. Will be worth investigating on this rather than going with own Doc-CE